# Why is my multi-threaded code not faster?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm running this in a console application:

```
public void ForEachParallel(Action<TElement> action)
{
    var elements = new Queue<TElement>(_set);

    var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, _threadCount)
                          .Where(index => elements.Any())
                          .Select(index => elements.Dequeue())
                          .Select(element => Task.Run(() => action(element)))
                          .ToList();

    while (tasks.Any())
    {
        var index = Task.WaitAny(tasks.ToArray());

        tasks.RemoveAt(index);

        if (elements.Any())
        {
            var element = elements.Dequeue();
            tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => action(element)));
        }

    }

}
```

I have an equivalent `ForEach` method that does all of this in a serial way. I'm using 10 threads, but the `ForEachParallel` is taking just as much time as the `ForEach`. I have an i7 with 6 cores. Either this has a whole lot of overhead, or it is somehow running these tasks with a single thread.

Each action is an independent read, process, and write.

Comment: A lot of it depends on the "action" you are trying to run.  There's a fixed overhead that you incur by the process of parallelizing these.  Also depending on what you are doing inside, if you are accessing memory, that might actually not be parallel at all.

Comment: If it was the same thread it would all deadlocked because `WaitAny` is a blocking call. Is your processing CPU bound?

Comment: Have you tried running in `Parallel.ForEach` just to see if you get the same result?  If that's a lot faster you can at least be more confident it's a problem with your method.

Comment: If you have 6 cores, then try 6 threads. You cannot over parallel the cores.

Comment: I really feel that there is just something going one that is not letting me create threads. I have a distant memory of a console app not allowing more than one thread by default. I have done the analysis on this. There just shouldn't be enough overhead for it to take this long. I'm planning on testing it with Parallel.ForEach tomorrow, but I don't think it will be any different.

The threads debug window is completely dead. I am using .NET core.

Comment: @Jordan - The difficulty in asking questions here is really about the effort required to ask a good question. If the community didn't spend so much effort on this the quality of the site would be terrible. We bother because of the value that is generated through the effort.

Comment: @Jordan - Could you please edit your question to give us a [mcve]? I'd love to run your code and see what you're seeing.

Comment: @Jordan - You also know that `Queue<T>` is not threadsafe?

Comment: @Jordan - You know that there are libraries that handle this kind of thing right out of the box? `elements.ToObservable().Select(x => Observable.Start(() => action(x))).Merge(4);`

Comment: Linked as duplicate: [c# multithread - very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11392357/c-sharp-multithread-very-slow)

Comment: `.Select(index => elements.Dequeue())` oh, oh, oh! Side-effecty selector detected there! Don't do things like this, unless you like opening [popular issues on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/31554 "FirstOrDefault after OrderBy invokes predicate for every element (breaking change)"), asking why your code broke after the latest .NET upgrade.

Comment: Your `ForEachParallel` method looks like an attempt to reinvent the [`Parallel.ForEach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach) method. Could you explain what's wrong with the built-in `Parallel.ForEach`, and why you need to write a custom implementation from scratch? I am asking because it's quite possible that your multi-threaded code is not only slow, but also buggy.

Comment: @Jordan **Obviously** we cannot know why your program is slow without knowing what `action` does and from such fragment of code. You have to produce a minimal example and give statistics. Also, there is a very high probability that your performance problem is not in the above code like contention for a shared resource.

Comment: @Enigmativity `Queue` not being thread-safe is not an issue based on the code we can see since the dequeuing is all on one thread (although it could be a problem if items are being enqueued in a separate thread / task). But yes, we can't help much without a [mcve]. The key issue is what `action` is, and the OP seems reluctant to share that.

Comment: @Jordan - I just ran a test using your code and it is indeed faster than running it in series. I compared it against the same implementation using Observables and it is just as fast. Clearly the issue is in your `action` code.

Comment: I'm using `DotNetZip` to extract zip entries from a password-protected file in one area and compressing them into another directory. I'm being very careful not to share a memory. I'm new-ing up a new ZipFile each time, but you are right. `DotNetZip` might be using some static memory that might make multi-threading impossible though I wouldn't think so.

Comment: I'm starting to think that the issue is that the file system is inherently serial. The last time I tried this pattern there was significant processing time in memory and so that was mitigated by separating into threads. The processing I'm doing now is very IO intensive and so maybe that's why it feels serial.

Comment: That's got to be it. I repeated the same logic with a stripped-down `Parallel.ForEach` and it was no faster than a serial `foreach`. That clinches it. I'm leaning to heavy on the disk. Thank you everyone for your grace, understanding, and helpfulness.

Comment: The file system is not *inherently* serial, it's just that disks perform far better when doing sequential reading rather than random read, if that is what you are doing

Comment: @Jordan - When the time spent doing I/O is significant compared CPU usage then the benefit of multithreading diminishes rapidly.

Comment: @Enigmativity That is exactly what I'm coming to understand.

Comment: @Charlieface, I can't imagine the head on a magnetic drive reading the disk randomly or in anything way that could be called parallel. I'm thinking that working with files is inherently non-parallel. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Obviously magnetic head can't do random reads at the same time. But disks have caches, as do drivers, both of which can serve in parallel. And even a sequential read from a magnetic disk can serve requests for proximate data at the same time. Point is: it's not the file system, it's the disk.

Comment: @Charlieface, you have a point. I'm using DotNetZip. I would imagine it is streaming the zip file contents into memory and extracting it one entry at a time. So probably long sequential reads. Extraction will be performed as the file data is streaming, so the reads will be occurring nearly all the time. I imagine it is the same situation with compression and writes. I think this answers my question. It gives me something to tell my boss.

Comment: Jordan one performance optimization for doing mixed I/O-bound and CPU-bound work is task-parallelism. This means having two (or more) heterogeneous operations running concurrently and independently from each other. In your case one thread could be dedicated for doing the I/O-bound work (reading the files and pushing their raw contents to memory, and grabbing compressed data from memory and writing them to the disk), and another thread could be dedicated for doing the CPU-bound work (compress the in-memory data). The performance improvement might not be significant though.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - It's likely that the library is doing both the IO and the CPU work.

Comment: @Enigmativity surely, but most probably it's doing all the work on the calling thread. I assume that the I/O work and the CPU work are interleaved (not concurrent). But I may be wrong.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - I'm pretty certain the the library would do it in series.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - Division of labor. Have one thread read and write while the other is processing. I thought about doing this. But my larger goal is to create an apparatus that can be easily applied to other process applications to provide telemetry for multi-threaded apps running lists of processes (code left out above). That's why I'm using this specific algorithm. Thanks for your insight.

Comment: @Jordan this apparatus already exists, and it's called [`Parallel.ForEach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach). There is no need to reinvent it. 

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, it doesn't do what my apparatus does. My code does not just make the foreach parallel. It provides telemetry such as a time to completion, average run time. It allows me to make the read-out for the process, much more intelligent. I stripped it down to an MVP to demonstrate the problem I have. I am aware of existing technologies. :)

Comment: @Jordan wouldn't it be simpler to add this telemetry functionality on top of the `Parallel.ForEach`? This low level implementation that it's based on the `Task.WaitAny`, is inefficient to say the least. Continuations are attached and detached to N tasks on every loop, resulting to an O(n*m) complexity overall. Also replicating the correct failure behavior is quite tricky, and honestly I would be surprised if you've managed to get it right.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, First, I do not want to add any code to the worker thread. This interferes with my analysis. Second, I have tried Parallel.ForEach in this case. It wasn't any faster. My first attempt was to use Parallel.ForEach, but things became cumbersome for what I'm trying to do. I'm not done with development. I have a few other things to try. Ultimately, adding a telemetry harness to any process adds time to that process. The benefits of the harness should outweigh the loss from extra time. In the case I am using, I got about 3 seconds for 20,000 units back-of-the-envelope.

Comment: @Jordan one difference you should be aware of is that the `Parallel.ForEach` enumerates lazily the supplied `IEnumerable<T>`, making it possible to do parallel work on infinite sequences. Your implementation enumerates greedily the `_set`, and materializes it to a `Queue<T>`. So an infinite sequence will cause your implementation to fail with an out of memory exception.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, I know. I could change my pattern to incorporate delayed execution too, but it didn't seem necessary in a loop that had no other significant operations. `Parallel.ForEach` took the same amount of time as my solution did within seconds for 20,000+ operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my test code:

```
void Main()
{
    Action<int> action = n =>
    {
        Console.Write($" +{n} ");
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(n + 1));
        Console.Write($" {n}- ");
    };
    
    ForEachParallel(Enumerable.Range(0, 6), 4, action);
}

public void ForEachParallel<TElement>(IEnumerable<TElement> source, int threadCount, Action<TElement> action)
{
    var elements = new Queue<TElement>(source);

    var tasks =
        source
            .Take(threadCount)
            .Where(index => elements.Any())
            .Select(index => elements.Dequeue())
            .Select(element => Task.Run(() => action(element)))
            .ToList();

    while (tasks.Any())
    {
        var index = Task.WaitAny(tasks.ToArray());

        tasks.RemoveAt(index);

        if (elements.Any())
        {
            var element = elements.Dequeue();
            tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => action(element)));
        }
    }
}
```

It's a effectively the same as your `ForEachParallel` but I've made it more generic.

When I change the `threadCount` I get differing execution lengths. This is clearly running as expected.